# Python: To calculate nearest value for a group and assign remaining to other group in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

Have got two dataframe:
**df1**

```
Store  Category  split_table    tot_tables
11      FRUIT       7.0             12
11      VEG         5.0             12  
13      FRUIT       5.0             11
13      VEG         6.0             11
```

**df2**

```
Site    sum_list
11      [1,2,3,4,5,6.5,8,9.5,11,12]
13      [1,2,3,4,5,6.5,7.5,9,10,11]
```

have to generate new column `df1['final_table']` by following below points:

1. For **every store** and '**FRUIT**' category in df1, '`final_table`' value is calculated by taking the nearest value from `df2['sum_list']` from respective store.
2. For **every store** and '**VEG**' category in df1, '`final_table`' value is calculated by `df1['tot_tables'] - 'newly calculated 'final_table' for FRUIT category'`. So that, sum of final_table value for each store is equivalent to tot_table.

**Expected Output:**
**df1**

```
Store  Category  split_table    tot_tables      final_table
11      FRUIT       7.0             12              6.5
11      VEG         5.0             12              5.5 
13      FRUIT       5.0             11              5.0
13      VEG         6.0             11              6.0
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have only one FRUIT and VEG in each store:

```py
# calculate fruit
m = df2.set_index("Site")["sum_list"].to_dict()
mask = df1["Category"].eq("FRUIT")
df1.loc[mask, "final_table"] = df1[mask].apply(
    lambda x: min(m[x["Store"]], key=lambda y: abs(y - x["split_table"])),
    axis=1,
)

# calculate vegetable
m = df1[mask].set_index("Store")["final_table"].to_dict()
mask = df1["Category"].eq("VEG")
df1.loc[mask, "final_table"] = df1[mask].apply(
    lambda x: x["tot_tables"] - m[x["Store"]],
    axis=1,
)

print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   Store Category  split_table  tot_tables  final_table
0     11    FRUIT          7.0          12          6.5
1     11      VEG          5.0          12          5.5
2     13    FRUIT          5.0          11          5.0
3     13      VEG          6.0          11          6.0
```